# Panda query with condition "boolean label can not be used"

Tags: python, dataframe

I have following dataframe

```
    publisher_name   show_name  UniqueCount_promo_code UniqueValue_promo_code
0  publisher_name1  show_name1                       2              [code1, ]
1  publisher_name1  show_name2                       1                [code2]
2  publisher_name2  show_name3                       2         [code3, code4]
```

trying to do a query on UniqueValue_promo_code

```
condition1 = lambda x: any(val == '' or val is None for val in x) and len(x) == 2
data = result.query(f"{condition1('UniqueValue_promo_code')} ")
```

gettig error

> raise KeyError( KeyError: 'False: boolean label can not be used
> without a boolean index'

What is wrong here
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .query only expects boolean expressions as strings. It wont't work with a lambda function. You can re-write this as:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'publisher_name': ['publisher_name1', 'publisher_name1', 'publisher_name2'],
    'show_name': ['show_name1', 'show_name2', 'show_name3'],
    'UniqueCount_promo_code': [2, 1, 2],
    'UniqueValue_promo_code': [['code1', ''], ['code2'], ['code3', 'code4']]
})

condition = (data['UniqueValue_promo_code'].apply(lambda x: any(val == '' or val is None for val in x)) &
             (data['UniqueCount_promo_code'] == 2))

filtered_data = data[condition]
print(filtered_data)
```